# C++ Qt get return value of sub-python process

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

I'm trying to get the return value of the external python script.

I tried this to get return value but it doesn't work.

```
QStringList arguments { "example.py", "--argv",path_of_image  };
QProcess p;
p.start("python", arguments);
return_value=p.readLine();//also I tried p.readAllStandardOutput()

p.waitForFinished();

qDebug()<<return_value;
```

This  prints "" , I can't get the value.

Comment: Do you want the exit code or the stdout of the python process? `p.exitCode()` will return you a int. `readLine()` and `readAllStandardOutput()` gives you the stdout. So if that's what you want and you are getting empty strings, then you should check if you are calling example.py with the correct arguements.

Comment: My python script returning a string value, I'm trying to get this valued

Comment: print(value)
return value
These are last 2 lines of my script

Comment: How can I get the return value of script

Answer (score 0):

I found it

```
QProcess process;
QString scriptFile =  "example.py";

QString pythonCommand = "python " + scriptFile + " --arg " ;





process.start(pythonCommand);
process.execute(pythonCommand);



process.waitForFinished(1000);
returned=process.readAllStandardOutput();
```